# Simple space effect in Audacity on Mac OS X

Tags: audacity, panning, echo

How to create a simple sound effect which makes the sound go from the left ear to the right and so on, in a "perpetual" loop (preferably with Audacity on Mac OS X)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a left-right sci-fi sounds using the **Phaser** and **Wahwah** effects. Both come included in the OS X distribution.

1. Create a sound, if you're not using own material: **Generate/Tone**.
2. Make a copy of this mono track: **Edit/Duplicate**.
3. Make it stereo: In the track menu (right of the X/delete button) use "**Make Stereo Track**".
4. Use either **Effect/Phaser** or **Effect/Wahwah** or both, depending on what reult you are looking for.

This answer is available as a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/jFUC9zw8ORY).

Answer (score 1):

1. If the track is stereo (two curves in one track): click on the name of the track and select "Split Stereo Track". If the track is a mono track (one curve), select the track and make a duplicate of the track (Edit menu).
2. Set the L | R track balance to 100% Left for the upper and 100% Right for the lower.
3. Select the first half the upper track and apply a "Fade In" (Effect menu)
4. Select the last half the upper track and apply a "Fade Out" (Effect menu)
5. Select the first half the lower track and apply a "Fade Out" (Effect menu)
6. Select the last half the lower track and apply a "Fade In" (Effect menu)